# Restrict user rights in SP2010, so they CAN ADD list items but CANNOT EDIT them once saved?

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, rights-management

I appreciate if you can help me with this. My wonderful company uses SP2010, and I got the task to solve this issue using it - though I am not a programmer (basic html is still ok).

I need a simple annual leave list with the following capabilities:

1. Group of users (~100 members) should be able to create list items in a list that contains annual leave data. Columns are: Name, Leave start date, Leave end date, Team leader, etc.
2. Once they fill in the new item form, a workflow notifies the team leader to visit the item and set a column "approval status" to "approved" or "rejected".
3. Based on this column value, another workflow notifies the requestor about the decision.

**4. After line manager sets the column to approved, item should be locked, so the users should be able to see their items in the list, but they should not be able to edit it.**

Sounds so simple, but I have big issues with point 4. as Sharepoint does not differentiate create and edit rights to a list item. As a result, requestor can edit dates of the approved items.

Any hints how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint does differenciate between create and edit rights, just not in the default permission levels. You are free to create your own permission levels if you need to. (You could also modify the default permission levels but I would advise against it as it can only lead to confusion.) More information on this subject can be found on TechNet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239(v=office.14).aspx

That being said, I don't think this approach is the solution to your problem. You could use your workflow to assign item level permissions (read only) to the approved items. If you are creating your workflows via SharePoint Designer, this link may prove useful: http://spcycle.blogspot.be/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html